# UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to change the selected `UITableViewCell`, but a little weird thing is happening here. I have placed the two images. Please take a look:
[image][image]

When I select the 'early' cell, it turns blue. It moves to the 'early blah blah' `UIViewController`. Then when I hit the 'Find' `UIButton`, it goes back to the first view.
It works, but the cell is still selected blue! So I wrote some code as below:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    if ([_currentMethod isEqual: @"searchIt"]) {

        if (indexPath.row == 0) {
            BookMark2ViewController* bookMark2 = [[BookMark2ViewController alloc] init];


            UITableViewCell* cell = [self tableView:_tableView
                                            cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;



            [self.navigationController pushViewController:bookMark2 animated:YES];

        }else if (indexPath.row == 1) {
            BookMarkViewController* bookMark1 = [[BookMarkViewController alloc] init];

            [self.navigationController pushViewController:bookMark1 animated:YES];

        }
    }
```

The two lines right in the middle of the code:

```
        UITableViewCell* cell = [self tableView:_tableView
                                        cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

These two lines didn't work. Does any one know how to fix this?

Comment: set the breakpoint on cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone; and check whether it is calling or not

Comment: these 2 lines should be in the dataSource not in the delegate.!!
put these lines inside the cellForRowAtIndexPath .

Comment: @Erik Hi, thanks for the tips. Yes, it is executed, but doesn't work for me.

Comment: @M.Othman Thanks! I'll take your advice!

Comment: Also, the lines of code, `UITableViewCell* cell = [self tableView:_tableView                      cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;` doesnt make any sense to be here for the purpose of `deselecting` the cell.

Answer (score 5):

If you dont want the cells to show selection at all, place `cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone` in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

if you want the cell to be selected and then deselect, place

```
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
```

in your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`

hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

```
UITableViewCell* cell = [self tableView:_tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
// Make sure your cell is not nil.
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

I had a such situation.

Comment: Which cell are you talking about?  Maybe you could provide a little more context around your answer.